# Changing a value in Razor html using button and JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, daypilot

Here is a (not complete, because there is too much code) View of my calendar

```
@using DayPilot.Web.Mvc;
@using DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Events.Calendar;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DayPilot/daypilot-all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
        @Html.DayPilotCalendar("dp", new DayPilotCalendarConfig
        {
            BackendUrl = Url.Action("Backend", "Calendar"),
            ViewType = DayPilot.Web.Mvc.Enums.Calendar.ViewType.Week,
        })
    </div>

<button id="Day">Day</button>
<button id="Week">Week</button>
<button id="Month">Month</button>
```

How can I change a value, such as ViewType, using button click and JavaScript?

Comment: http://www.daypilot.org/api/pro/latest/html/P_DayPilot_Web_Ui_DayPilotCalendar_ViewType.htm

Comment: https://doc.daypilot.org/calendar/resources-view/

Comment: I mean how can I change any value of this object I create (its DayPilotCalendarConfig properties). I want to have buttons which will be able to change ViewType and BackendUrl by clicking on them.

Comment: OK, create a prototype of what your trying to do, and post the code here.

Comment: Updated. I would like to change the ViewType to Day/Week/Month depend on which button was clicked using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with DayPilot, but judging from their API, using javascript (wo/ jquery), you'd write something like this:

```
(function()
{
    var dpc = new DayPilot.Calendar("dp");
    dpc.startDate = "2013-03-25";
    dpc.viewType = "Week";
    dpc.update();
    var updateCalendar = function(viewType)
    {
        dpc.viewType = viewType;
        dpc.update();
    };

    document.getElementById('Day').addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        updateCalendar('Day');
    });
    document.getElementById('Week').addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        updateCalendar('Week');
    });
    document.getElementById('Month').addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        updateCalendar('Month');
    });
})();
```

Using jQuery, it'd look something like this:

```
(function($)
{
    var dpc = new DayPilot.Calendar("dp");
    dpc.startDate = "2013-03-25";
    dpc.viewType = "Week";
    dpc.update();

    $(document).on('click', '#Day, #Week, #Month', function(e)
    {    
        dpc.viewType = $(e.target).attr('id'); //realistically, this should probably be a data-attribute or what not
        dpc.update();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You'd still keep your Razor code, and you should just be able to add these JS calls or something similar. Getting the DayPilotCalendar object is probably the harder part, and it's not quite clear how to do that. Let me know if this helps at all.